# Can't visit www.ubuntu.com?

Tags: downloads

I can't download Ubuntu 12.04 may be due to the traffic right now. Can someone please provide a link for Ubuntu 12.04 Intel 32bit Desktop iso OFFICIAL TORRENT?

Comment: Well, be patient :]
It seems that Ubuntu is really popular :D

Comment: People can't wait! That's why they provide torrents..

Comment: This question  may close as too localised after some days :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have options:

- [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) or
- [Official CD Mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors)

Answer (score 2):

Although [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com) is currently down, the actual page contain the releases is still up and working here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

The link you're looking for is: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent

Comment: Coool Thanks! (...wow you got a GOLD badge.. so do you mind if support the guy below?? )

Comment: @Naveen Your question, your rules ;)

Comment: also，all guys can download Ubuntu 12.04 ISO from your country/area's image sync website.That's a good choice for now.